# Dynamic cast using Type of object C#

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, dynamic-cast

I have one abstract class named A, and other classes (B, C, D, E, ...) that implements A

I also have a list of A objects.
I'd like to be able to cast dynamicly each of the object in that list to their "base" type (ie B, C, D, ...) to be able to call their constructor in an other method.

Here is what I have done for now :

```
abstract class A { }
class B : A { }
class C : A { }
class D : A { }
class E : A { }
// ... 

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<A> list = new List<A> { new B(), new C(), new D(), new E() };
        // ...

        foreach (A item in list)
        {
            A obj  = foo(item);
        }
    }

    public static A foo(A obj)
    {
        if (obj.GetType() == typeof(B))
        {
            return bar((B)obj);
        }
        else if (obj.GetType() == typeof(C))
        {
            return bar((C)obj);
        }
        // ... same for D, E, ...
        return null;
    }

    public static T bar<T>(T obj) where T : class, new()
    {
        // To use the constructor, I can't have here an abstract class.
        T newObj = new T();
        return newObj;
    }
```

It works, but I'd like to find an other way but to test for each class that implements A if their type equals the type of my object, and cast it afterwards.

I have nearly 15 classes like B, C, D, ... and I might have more. 
In order to have something simple, clear and maintainable, I'd like to avoid this methods, and the 15+ "if(...) else(...)".

Do you see a way to do so ?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve here? Did you consider defining an abstract method in A and overriding them in subclasses. So instead of constructors you can call overridden methods in individual classes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Modify `bar` in this way:

```
public static T bar<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as T;
}
```

Then modify `foo`:

```
public static A foo(A obj)
{
    return bar(obj);
}
```

Note that I had to remove the `new()` constraint. That had to be done to avoid casting your `obj` inside of `foo`. You can check at runtime if the type has a parameterless constructor, though.

Comment: This is not making use of abstract class or generics. No type safety

Comment: @NasmiSabeer Safety can be achieved through additional Reflection checks in the `bar` method. It's his responsibility to write them. I believe that there aren't other ways, given the author's requirements.

Comment: @Eve I agree this is the best way we can do from the info he's given. But I feel he has written some logic inside the ctors and trying to make sure that logic gets called for each type. That's definitely an anti-pattern. abstract, virtual and overriding are for the very same purpose.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks! it helped me a lot for my dynamic model method)